# Can't get header in AuthServiceProvider in laravel/lumen v5.6

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to authorize user in middleware for this purpose i am sending user token in headers from postman. But when i receive headers in AuthServiceProvider headers or empty like below object

```
app('request')->headers

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag Object
(
    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [cacheControl:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

now I want to get headers and store authenticated user object in Auth::user() how i can achieve this milestone.

Comment: Did you enable facades?

Comment: @Quezler yes i have enbaled the facades in bootstrap/app.php file

Answer (score 0):

HeaderBag object has a protected header property so you can't see it with a var_dump.
what did you get with `app('request')->headers->all();` ?

Comment: i am getting empty array instead of headers even i am sending APIKEY and USERTOKEN in request headers